# Pass the onMouseDownMap X, Y from a python addin to a toolbox script tool

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, python-script-tool

Is it possible to pass the onMouseDownMap X, Y coordinates to a script tool launched using GPToolDialog?

The end goal is to have the user select the add-in tool, click the map to add a point, then pop up the script tool to attribute the point.

```
class LOMA_Point(object):
"""Implementation for Stormwater_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.cursor = 3
    self.shape = 'NONE'
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    message = 'Your mouse clicked:' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y)
    pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, 'My Coordinates')
    toolbox = r'Database Management Tools.tbx'
    pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(toolbox, 'AddLOMA')
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [pythonaddins page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm) the only 2 parameters used by the GPToolDialog() are the toolbox path and the tool name. There is no mechanism to pass on the XY values.

An alternative approach would be to write the XY values to a well known location such as c:\temp. So your code in the onMouseDownMap event would create a dbase file with 2 fields X and Y and 1 row. Then your tool AddLOMA which I assume is a model can extract these values using the model only [Get Field Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm) tool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up dumping the coordinates into a temporary pickle file then had a pyt toolbox tool read the pickle file in the updateParameters function.